# Very High Correlations In Forex Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics, regression

I have a **regression** problem where I'm working on predicting future close price value change of a certain **forex** pair, mainly `USDJPY`, so I did the following:

1. Get the **forex** historical data of `USDJPY` pair between *2001 & 2017*, where it has the following attributes `Open, High, Low, Close, Volume` (*per 15 minuets*).
2. Grab each 50 records and put them into one record in sequence as `X1Open, X1High, X1Low, X1Close, X1Volume ....  X50Open, X50High, X50Low, X50Close, X50Volume`. **(Note: 1st 50 are from 1 ~ 50, 2nd from 2 ~ 51...etc)**
3. Added a new attribute called **'Slope'** to my new data that represents the angle (*normalized into some value*) of the regression line of the future close price of 25 points forward.`(Don't mind for details it simply represents the Label)`
4. Calculate **Bivariate Pearson Correlation** between all variables in my new dataset using `IBM SPSS` to search for `multi-collinearity` issues.

Here is the problem, where I found that the correlation between any independent variable and another was equal to **+1**, and the correlation between any independent variable and the dependent variable 'Slope' was said to be **-0.12**.

This doesn't make sense at all, how could the variable `X1Open` for example, be highly positively correlated (with +1) with `X37High`!! 
And how could all of the independent variables share the same correlation value with the dependent variable (-0.12)?!

- [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plo2bshrhpwekx7/usdjpy.rar?dl=0) you can find the full data after reformation ~ 500 MB.
- [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4f9v35hep1ehiar/data.xlsx?dl=0) is a sample    data in excel format of 500 record (use the
  CORREL formula to    calculate correlation e.g.
  `CORREL(B2:B500,C2:C500)`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data is a ~500 MB CSV file… I guess it'd be easier if you could present a smaller example that allows others to reproduce your issue, including the used Excel formulas. Otherwise it'll be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: @slhck thanks for your note, please check the edits

Comment: That's much better, thanks. I still don't know if I fully understand the issue. In your example data, you are asking why `B` is correlated highly with `FV`? It isn't – it's 0.68. Or is this about what SPSS is calculating? Either way it'd be best for you to point to the problem with the specific data you've shared in the tool where you're getting the problem.

Comment: @slhck thanks for your response, but what are the `B` and `FV` your are talking about? if you mean the independent variables and the future value (dependent) then you had got a part of it. I'm trying to get the correlation between each two variables alone (whether it is a dependent or independent one). For example, correl between `X1O and X5C`, or `X15L and X34C` or `X1H and Slope` etc.. so for example try to apply this formula `CORREL(B2:B500,C2:C500)` this will get the correlation between `X1O and X1H` that is about +1

Comment: Columns `B` and `FV`, since in your text you were referring to the correlation between `X1Open` (column `B` in the respective Excel sheet) and `X37High` (column `FV`). The correlation between `B2:B500` and `FV2:FV500` is 0.68. When I calculate the correlations between other columns (as you suggested) with R, I get values != 1: `cor(x10o, x5c) = 0.96, cor(x15l, x34c) = 0.85`. As for correlating the individual independent vars with slope, wouldn't you expect all of the same row to be very similarly correlated? Depends on the statistical purpose of that slope, at which point I'd have to pass.

Comment: When I plot the correlations of each independent ("open" value) against the slope, they seem very similar, so it doesn't surprise me that the actual Pearson correlation is the same, or similar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fIa2.png